# Dynamically changing the style of an element in a loop

Tags: javascript, styles, margin

I'm trying to have my 3 elements `marginLeft` differ from each other, with each following one being bigger by `300px` than the previous. Clearly, the 'px' making it a string is in the way, but I don't know how to overcome it.

```js
function render() {
  var gElOptions = document.querySelector('.options');

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var elOptionBtn = document.createElement('button');

    gElOptions.appendChild(elOptionBtn);
    elOptionBtn.setAttribute('class', `option-${i}`);
    var elOption = document.querySelector(`.option-${i}`);
    elOption.style.marginLeft = 1000 + 'px';
    // The problematic line:
    if (elOption.style.marginLeft === 1000 + 'px') elOption.style.marginLeft -= 300 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="render()">
  <div class="options">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this should by done by css. nth-of-type or child and then just set margin. If you use some preprocessor (sass, less) then you can do it in loop.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I'm having a hard time getting it to work. I did attempt to set the marginLeft in css, but I was still faced with dynamically changing the other 2 buttons. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function render() {
    var gElOptions = document.querySelector('.options');

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var elOptionBtn = document.createElement('button');
        elOptionBtn.innerHTML = i
        gElOptions.appendChild(elOptionBtn);
        elOptionBtn.setAttribute('class', `option-${i}`);
        //var elOption = document.querySelector(`.option-${i}`);
        elOptionBtn.style.marginLeft = i*300 + 'px';
        // The problematic line:
        //if (elOption.style.marginLeft === 1000 + 'px') elOption.style.marginLeft -=  300 + 'px';
    }
}

render()
```

```html
<div class="options"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Alan, while it does finally set the buttons at an equal position (thank you for this), it doesn't allow me to adjust them to the proper position I want on the page (attempting to marginLeft/Right them all on CSS messes up the result of your code, and suddenly they are no longer aligned next to each other at an equal distance but rather one is above another unevenly.

Comment: you mean when you run the code in stackoverflow window?

Comment: when you run the above code click on `Full page` to see the final result.

Comment: On my project I mean. The point is to have the buttons within the element of gElOptions (the div containing the buttons). When I run the code - while it does finally set them at an equal distance from each other with marginLeft, I have no way to keep them in boundaries of the visual image of gElOptions, and 2 of the buttons escape the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Js is only for dynamic adding buttons. (arrow right, arrow left).

Margin for each button is set in css.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div');

const addButton = () => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = "test"
  container.appendChild(button);
}

const delButton = () => {
 container.lastChild?.remove()
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
  switch(key){
    case "ArrowLeft": {
      delButton();
      break;
    }
    case "ArrowRight": {
       addButton();
    }
  }
  
})
```

```css
button{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button:nth-child(1){
  margin-left: 10px;
}
button:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 20px;
}
button:nth-child(3){
  margin-left: 30px;
}
button:nth-child(4){
  margin-left: 40px;
}
button:nth-child(5){
  margin-left: 50px;
}
button:nth-child(6){
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
```